# How to normalize axis in SharpGL view to match OpenGL defaults?

Tags: c#, opengl, sharpgl

I wanted to have a quick 3D object in my Winforms C# app, so I connected [SharpGL](https://github.com/dwmkerr/sharpgl) library to my project. It was straightforward to use. However, I noticed that its axis does not follow the general OpenGL defaults with Y axis being vertical. For SharpGL, Z axis is vertical. This makes working with it a bit confusing since many OpenGL (and OpenVR) examples need adjustments.

How do I rotate the default SharpGL camera to match the expected OpenGL default view?

I can move the camera using

```
sceneControl.Scene.CurrentCamera.Position = new SharpGL.SceneGraph.Vertex(5, 5, 5);
```

but there is no method for rotation.